# How to 301 redirect entire .php files to the URL without .php in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

We have a large `.php` based static website.

*How 301 redirect all its URLs from `.php` to Url without `.php`?*

```
For e.g 
/about-us.php *- should 301 redirect to -* /about-us 
/contact.php *- should 301 redirect to -* /contact
/meet-the-team.php *- should 301 redirect to -* /meet-the-team
```

As we have a large number of URLs, we wish to have few lines of code in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava for your quick response.. I will check the above code and will update if it works or not for me.. I hope this will work well for the URLs which are placed to the domain root also.. :)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks that worked for me.
However I had to make only a small change. 
Had to change the last line to 301 from 302

RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

Comment: I intentionally use 302 for testing otherwise browser cache 301 results that makes testing difficult. Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.